# Unable to load the series without duplication on highchart using angular 4

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have implemented highchart in an angular 4 application. My highchart seems to load the same series twice.  There is method called addseries which i am calling from with the @Input() set stressTestResults declaration. I can see the break point hitting twice there and calling the addseries twice. I am not sure how to prevent this being called twice. If i move the addseries to the ngOnInit, it then doesnt get the value by the time the chart is loaded and on refresh of the page , I can see the value coming through. This time it shows correctly one series. If Init is the correct place then there is some issue with change detection or lag from retrieving the data. Could somebody tell me where am  I going wrong

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { StressTestAnalysis } from '../../../../api/dtos';
import { ReactiveComponent } from '@wtw/toolkit/src/utils/base.component';
import { SplineChartComponent } from '../../../../shared/Highcharts/spline/spline-chart.component';

export interface ChartSeries {
  data: number[][];
  name: string;
  color: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stress-test-analysis',
  templateUrl: './stress-test-analysis.component.html'
})

export class StressTestAnalysisComponent extends ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
  isExpanded = false;
  showTable = true;
  private results: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];
  @ViewChild(SplineChartComponent) public stressSplineChart: SplineChartComponent;
  //@Input() results: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];

  @Input() set stressTestResults(value: Array<StressTestAnalysis>) {
    this.results = value;
    this.addSeries();

  }

  public chartSeries: Array<ChartSeries> = [];
  seriesName: string;
  strategyName: string = '';
  constructor(
  ) { super(); }

  ngOnInit() {
  // this.addSeries();
  }

  private addSeries() {

    if (this.results === null) {
      return;
    }

    this.results.forEach(element => {
      if (element !== null) {
          this.chartSeries.push({ data: element.graphData, name: element.seriesName, color: element.color });
        //  if (this.stressSplineChart) this.stressSplineChart.redraw();
      }
    });
  }

}
```

**Parent component html**

you can see here that i have initialized the stressTestResults to the stressTestResults property of the child component

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3 mb-3 test-feasibility--details">
  <app-assumptions-summary></app-assumptions-summary>
</div>
<form #pageForm="ngForm">
  <div class="container-fluid base_strategy p-0 m-0">
    <div class="tb-container col-md-12 p-0 m-0 scroll-auto">
      <app-strategies [strategies]="run.strategies" [linesOfBusinessInput]="run.linesOfBusinessInput"  [redraw]="forceRedraw" (applyChange)="applyChange($event)" (save)="save()"></app-strategies>
      <div class="col-12 test_feasibility--accordion">
        <!-- Accordion -->
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist">

          <app-net-present-value-analysis [npvResults]="npvResults"></app-net-present-value-analysis>

          <app-economic-value-analysis [evResults]="evResults"></app-economic-value-analysis>

          <app-stress-test-analysis [stressTestResults]="stressTestResults"></app-stress-test-analysis>

          <app-ending-surplus-analysis [results]="endingSurplusResults"></app-ending-surplus-analysis>

        </div>
        <!-- Accordion End -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Chart component

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'splinechart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
    chart {
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
         padding:0;
      }`]
})

export class SplineChartComponent implements OnChanges {
    public options: any;
    chart: any;

    @Input() public series: any;
    @Input() public yaxisdata: any;
    @Input() public selectedRating: string = '';

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService) {
        this.options = {
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                margin: 25,
                itemMarginTop: 0,
                symbolRadius: 0,
                symbolHeight: 20,
                symbolWidth: 20,
                useHTML: true,
                    title: {
                    text: this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.GRAPH_LEGEND_TITLE'),
                    margin: 50,
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic',
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.STA.GRAPH_XAXIS')
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.STA.GRAPH_YAXIS')
                }
            },

            tooltip: {

            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    events: {

                        legendItemClick: function() {
                            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item path');
                            for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                                elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
                                elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-height', '20');
                            }
                            this.chart.redraw();
                        }

                    },

                    allowPointSelect: true,

                },
                spline: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle'

                    },
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    showInLegend: false
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }

    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;

         var seriesLength = this.chart.series.length;
        for(var i = seriesLength -1; i > -1; i--) {
            this.chart.series[i].remove();
        }

        data.series.currentValue.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

   public redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;

        //   var seriesLength = this.chart.series.length;
        // for(var i = seriesLength -1; i > -1; i--) {
        //     this.chart.series[i].remove();
        // }

        this.series.map(s => {
            if (s !== null)
                this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });

        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item path');
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-height', '20');
        }
        this.chart.redraw();

    }

}
```

Parent component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { RunService, NavBarService } from '@wtw/platform/services';
import { Base } from '@wtw/toolkit';
import { NpvAnalysis, EvAnalysis } from '../../../shared/models/results';
import { Dto } from '@wtw/platform/api';
import { Strategy, StressTestAnalysis, CaptivesRun, EndingSurplus } from '../../../api/dtos';
import { RunModel } from '@wtw/platform/api/dtos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html'
})
export class ResultsComponent extends Base.ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
  run: CaptivesRun;
  npvResults: Array<NpvAnalysis> = [];
  evResults: Array<EvAnalysis> = [];
  stressTestResults: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];
  endingSurplusResults: Array<EndingSurplus> = [];
  forceRedraw: { value: number };
  private _baseRun: Dto.RunModel;

  constructor(
    private _runService: RunService,
    private _navBarService: NavBarService,
    private _translate: TranslateService,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._subscriptions = [
      this._runService.activeRun.subscribe((r: any) => {
        this._processRun(r);
      }),
      this._runService.currencyConverted.subscribe(r => {
        this._processRun(r);
        this.save();
        this.forceRedraw = { value: Math.random() * 10000 };
      }),
      this._navBarService.downloadReportEvent.subscribe(x => {
        this.downloadReport();
      })
    ];
  }

  downloadReport() {
    console.log('download report');
  }

  applyChange(event: any) {
    this.run.strategies.splice(event.index, 1, event.strategy);
    this._baseRun.data = this.run;
    this._runTrigger2(this._baseRun, event.index);
  }

  save() {
    this._baseRun.data = this.run;
    this._runService.persist(this._baseRun.runId, this.run, this._baseRun.currencyInfo).uiSignal('save').subscribe(x => {
      this._processResults(this.run.strategies);
    });
  }

  private _runTrigger2(r: Dto.RunModel, strategyIndex: number) {
    this._runService.executeTrigger(r.runId, this.run, { number: 2, param: strategyIndex.toString() }, r.currencyInfo)
      .uiSignal('trigger 2')
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.run = x.data;
        this._processResults(x.data.strategies);
      });
  }

  private _processRun(r: RunModel) {
    this._baseRun = r;
    this.run = r.data as CaptivesRun;

    // Initialising the data
    if (this.run.strategies) {
      if (!this.run.strategies[0].results) {
        this._runTrigger2(this._baseRun, 0);
      } else {
        this._processResults(this.run.strategies);
      }
    }
  }

  private _processResults(strategies: Array<Strategy>) {
    this.npvResults = new Array();
    this.evResults = new Array();
    this.endingSurplusResults = new Array();
    this.stressTestResults = new Array();
    const strategyTranslation = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.STRATEGY');

    const getStrategyName = (strategy: Strategy, index: number) => {
      let name = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.BASE_STRATEGY');
      if (index > 0) {
        name = strategyTranslation + ' ' + index;
      }
      return name;
    };

    strategies.forEach((strategy, index) => {
      const strategyName = getStrategyName(strategy, index);
      const results = strategy.results;
      this.npvResults.push(Object.assign(results.npvResult, { strategyName }));
      this.evResults.push(Object.assign(results.evaResult, { strategyName }));
      this.endingSurplusResults.push(Object.assign(results.endingSurplus));
      this.stressTestResults.push(Object.assign(results.stressResult));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried just sending in your array as the input property, then in `ngOnit` calling the `addSeries` method? I see you have it commented out in the code, but you didn't really touch on that in your question. I'm assuming that does NOT work?

Comment: Yes. I tried that but that didnt work

Comment: So, as written, it looks like you are calling `addSeries` twice. Once in the `@Input` and once in `ngOnInit()`. Is that intentional? If you remove from the `@Input`, it does not do what you want? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Sorry its meant to call only once. Either in OnInit or the property declaration. I have missed commenting in the post .Just updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the array in the `@Input` (and ONLY setting the data, don't call `addSeries()`). Then implement `onChanges`, and in `ngOnChanges` call your `addSeries` method. I think what's happening is that the `@Input` is being set as part of the ctor chain, but it's returning in `addSeries` because the data's not there yet, and it's never getting called again.

So something like:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stress-test-analysis',
  templateUrl: './stress-test-analysis.component.html'
})

export class StressTestAnalysisComponent extends ReactiveComponent implements OnChanges {
  isExpanded = false;
  showTable = true;
  private results: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];
  @ViewChild(SplineChartComponent) public stressSplineChart: SplineChartComponent;
  @Input() results: Array<StressTestAnalysis>;

  public chartSeries: Array<ChartSeries> = [];
  seriesName: string;
  strategyName: string = '';
  constructor(
  ) { super(); }

  ngOnChanges() {
   this.addSeries();
  }

  private addSeries() {

    if (!this.results) {
      return;
    }

    this.results.forEach(element => {
      if (element !== null) {
          this.chartSeries.push({ data: element.graphData, name: element.seriesName, color: element.color });
        //  if (this.stressSplineChart) this.stressSplineChart.redraw();
      }
    });
  }

}
```